# How to convert a date to format ddmmyy NOT ddmmyyyy

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am struggling to convert a date to format `ddmmyy` NOT `ddmmyyyy`.

The `convert` function allows all sorts of clever formatting but nothing close enough to fix using `REPLACE`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the datatype of the field either date or datetime?  If so, do you have to do this with sql or is any application code such as .net or java available to you?

Comment: The real question is do you need to convert to that format on SQL server? If you are sending the data to an app, the app should be responsible for formatting in most cases (usually it's much easier too!). If you are just dumping data out to a file or something of that nature, you can use `datepart(m, Date)` and pass d, m and y as separate parts. The problem is that it returns an `int` so you will have to format the values into the required string

Comment: If you really need to do your date formatting in SQL, here is a reference I find useful: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Answer (score 8):

dd/mm/yy is British\French standard, so try this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(8), [MyDateTime], 3), '/', '')
```

Comment: You want `CHAR(10)` otherwise the year is truncated

Comment: 103 will give you yyyy, he wants yy so it should be using 3 as the style instead

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 5),'-','')
```

format number 5 will do dd-mm-yy and then you can remove the -'s

Answer (score 0):

```
(concat(RIGHT('0' + CAST(DAY(getdate()) as varchar(2)), 2),RIGHT('0' + CAST(month(getdate()) as varchar(2)), 2),right(datepart(year,getdate()),(2))))
```

day

```
RIGHT('0' + CAST(DAY(getdate()) as varchar(2)), 2)
```

month

```
RIGHT('0' + CAST(month(getdate()) as varchar(2)), 2)
```

Year

```
right(datepart(year,getdate()),(2)))
```